# React 17.0.1: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, npm, eslint, react-dom

Very new react user here. I have been troubleshooting this error for hours now. I previously had this component working as a class, but it seems everyone is migrating towards functional components lately, so I'm trying to convert it. I did an intermediate conversion without using state and it worked fine, but I am having trouble converting username and password to state values.

When I use the following code, I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I have read through the linked troubleshooting page multiple times, and tried fixing all three possible causes with no success.

1. I am using `react` 17.0.1 and `react-dom` 17.0.1 in my `devDependencies`.
2. I have installed the `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` rule to identify if I am not using hooks correctly in my functional component.
3. I have used `npm ls react` and `npm ls react-dom` to confirm I do not have duplicate react versions.

LoginForm.jsx

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
const $ = require('jquery');

const LoginForm = ({ onToken }) => {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const submit = (event) => {
        // DO NOT POST PARAMS
        event.preventDefault();
        // AJAX username and password
        const loginData = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        };
        const options = {
            url: 'api/login',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(loginData),
            success: (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                onToken(data.token);
            }
        };

        $.ajax(options);

        console.log('Submitted!');
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submit}>
            <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label><br/>
            <input value={username} onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} type="text" id="username" name="username"/><br/>
            <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label><br/>
            <input value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} type="password" id="password" name="password"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
    );
};

LoginForm.propTypes = {
    onToken: PropTypes.func
};

export default LoginForm;
```

I have created a branch on my project's repository so you can view any other information:

Branch: https://github.com/GibsDev/node-password-manager/tree/login-conversion

Commit: [https://github.com/GibsDev/node-password-manager/commit/e0714b16bdbbf339fabf1aa4f6eefacd6d053427](https://github.com/GibsDev/node-password-manager/tree/login-conversion)

Comment: where this error happens, it seems your component is alright.

Comment: It occurs in the browser. When I try to view the page that includes this component. Maybe I am not adding the component correctly?
https://github.com/GibsDev/node-password-manager/blob/login-conversion/src/login.jsx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling this `loginForm` as if it was a *plain function*, not as a React component:

```
const loginForm = LoginForm({
    onToken: token => {
        const url = new URL(window.location.href);
        const returnurl = url.searchParams.get('returnurl');
        if (returnurl) {
            window.location.href = decodeURIComponent(returnurl);
        } else {
            window.location.href = '/';
        }
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(loginForm, domContainer);
```

As a result, it doesn't get wrapped in `React.createElement`, so it thinks the hook call is invalid.

Use JSX syntax instead:

```
const onToken = token => {
        const url = new URL(window.location.href);
        const returnurl = url.searchParams.get('returnurl');
        if (returnurl) {
            window.location.href = decodeURIComponent(returnurl);
        } else {
            window.location.href = '/';
        }
}

ReactDOM.render(<LoginForm onToken={onToken} />, domContainer);
          //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: It worked! Is there a javascript equivalent for doing this?

Comment: You can, but I wouldn't recommend it: `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(LoginForm, { onToken }), domContainer)`

Comment: Ahh, so you would still need to import React in that solution anyway. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I guess react 17 eliminate importing React itself when you only need jsx

Comment: @AmirhosseinEbrahimi Yeah, that's pretty cool: https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html Though it's more *obfuscating* that the element is being created through React than removing it completely

Comment: That is quite nice, I just enabled it within babel. Now I just need to figure out how to get ESLint to stop warning me about it.
https://babeljs.io/blog/2020/03/16/7.9.0#a-new-jsx-transform-11154httpsgithubcombabelbabelpull11154

Answer (score 1):

I got similar error in my repo. And it started appearing when I started bumping react from 16 to 17.
Later I realised its due to react16 is being pulled by the different dependency into node_modules and removing that fixed my issue