# React Admin Tutorial by Marmelab not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dom, react-admin

I am trying to follow this React-Admin tutorial by marmelab.com : https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html

After the following setup:

```
> npm create-react-app test-admin
> cd test-admin/
> npm install react-admin ra-data-json-server prop-types
> npm start
```

I tried running the following code as mentioned in the tutorial:

```
// in src/App.js
import * as React from "react";
import { Admin } from 'react-admin';
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';

const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com');
const App = () => <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} />;

export default App;
```

This gives me no output and a list of errors as follows:

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:86
error @ react-dom.development.js:60
render @ react-dom.development.js:29404
./src/index.js @ index.js:5
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
react.development.js:1476 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476:1)
    at useContext (react.development.js:1484:1)
    at CoreAdminContext (CoreAdminContext.js:12:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16141:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20838:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22342:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4157:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4206:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4270:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27243:1)
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1476
useContext @ react.development.js:1484
CoreAdminContext @ CoreAdminContext.js:12
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16141
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20838
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:22342
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4157
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4206
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4270
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27243
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26392
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26303
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26271
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25924
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:11982
flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:26040
legacyCreateRootFromDOMContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29309
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29335
render @ react-dom.development.js:29419
./src/index.js @ index.js:5
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
react-dom.development.js:18525 The above error occurred in the <CoreAdminContext> component:

    at CoreAdminContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:92536:28)
    at AdminContext
    at Admin (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:102485:25)
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18525
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18558
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13092
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13113
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23204
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24461
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24447
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24385
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26651
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26517
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25956
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:11982
flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:26040
legacyCreateRootFromDOMContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29309
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29335
render @ react-dom.development.js:29419
./src/index.js @ index.js:5
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
react.development.js:1476 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476:1)
    at useContext (react.development.js:1484:1)
    at CoreAdminContext (CoreAdminContext.js:12:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16141:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20838:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22342:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27219:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26392:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26303:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26271:1)
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1476
useContext @ react.development.js:1484
CoreAdminContext @ CoreAdminContext.js:12
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16141
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20838
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:22342
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27219
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26392
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26303
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26271
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25924
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:11982
flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:26040
legacyCreateRootFromDOMContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29309
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29335
render @ react-dom.development.js:29419
./src/index.js @ index.js:5
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
```

I am sure I am following the tutorial correctly.

1. Does this have anything to do with conflicting versions?
2. How do I fix this issue and continue with the tutorial?

My React version:

```
$ npm view react version
18.0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React 18 no longer supports `ReactDOM.render`, as they have replaced it with `createRoot`.

You can learn more about it here: [React v18.0](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html)

You can continue with the tutorial by just downgrading to React 17:

```
npm install --save react@17.0.2 react-dom@17.0.2
```

Comment: Should I create a new react app and then install it in that directory? or should I install this first and then create the app?

Comment: I tried this which fixed the ReactDOM.render error but the invalid hooks error is still there.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65982665/react-17-0-1-invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of

Answer (score 1):

You must change index.js file.

```
import ReactDom from 'react-dom/client'
const root = ReactDOM.creatorRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App/>);
```